# bing maps not working properly unity in WebGL export

Tags: bing-maps, bing

[bing maps not working properly unity in WebGL export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL93G.jpg)

how to salove this issue
it seems like the map object is being displayed, but the map itself is not loading.
this is and basic scene with no code. the only thing I added is the camera movement code. others are default settings in unity.

Comment: The Unity SDK has been officially deprecated, so should not be used for any new projects.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected - check the documentation. The Bing maps unity control only supports desktop targets due to native code dependencies. Also this control is an unsupported garage project which shouldn't be used for any production applications.